# Unit test case view controller crash swift

Tags: unit-testing, swift, ios8

I am writing unit test cases for the view controllers in my iOS app. I am trying to test if the UI elements involving IBOutlets are not nil as in the code below.

```
class ClientsViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

var clientsVC: ClientsTableViewController?

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Clients", bundle: nil)

    clientsVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? ClientsTableViewController

    if let vc = clientsVC?{
        vc.loadView()
    }
}

override func tearDown() {

    super.tearDown()
    clientsVC = nil
}

func testClientViewControllerNotNil(){

    XCTAssertNotNil(clientsVC, "view controller cannot be nil")
}
```

I test fails and outputs `"view controller cannot be nil"`

I fail to understand why.However, the below test passes:

```
func testStoryBoard(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainVC") as UIViewController
    XCTAssertNotNil(vc,"Storyboard is not connected with a viewcontroller")
```

But I need to do it in the 1st method as I want to test for the IBOutlet bindings for the Specific viewController like:

```
XCAssertNotNil(vc.sendButton, "Send button is nil")
```

Kindly guide me why the test is failing and also how to test outlet binding and the action binding in ViewControllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of trial n error we figured out the following code works for us. The issue was we were passing 'nil' value in `bundle` parameter. When this was replaced with the following line it started to work.
`bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))`

The working code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Clients", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))

var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ClientsVCTable") as ClientsTableViewController

vc.loadView()

XCTAssertNotNil(vc.clientSearchBar,"Not Nil")
```

Also for the IBActions:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))

var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController

vc.loadView()

let actions : NSArray = vc.signInButton.actionsForTarget(vc, forControlEvent: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)!

XCTAssertTrue(actions.containsObject("login"), "IBActions not found")
```

Comment: it will break in swift 1.2

Comment: From Apple's documentation: "You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil." (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) So I think a better approach would be to do this ```let _ = vc.view``` instead of ```vc.loadView()```

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point inside setUp method to check clientsVC object is initialized or not. try **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier**("Client") method to initialize.

Keep in mind that setUp and tearDown method will be called before and after the execution of each test method in the class respectively.